# Closure won't capture argument

Tags: rust

I'm a beginner in Rust, I took an example from a tutorial and decided to play around.
The  function fn new , in Cacher, does not see the second argument, here is closure, i trying to pass |num,num2|. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. We work with one argument

```
struct Cacher<T>

where
T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<u32>,
    multiplication : T,
}



impl<T> Cacher<T>
where
    T:  Fn(u32) -> u32,
{   
    fn new(calculation: T, multiplication : T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: None, 
            multiplication,
        }
    }
fn generate_workout(intensity: u32, random_number: u32, test_test_multiplication: u32,) {
    let mut expensive_result = Cacher::new( |num,num2|  {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        num + num2
    });
```

Here is the error

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied
  --> src/main.rs:43:32
   |
43 |       let mut expensive_result = Cacher::new( |num,num2|  {
   |  ________________________________^^^^^^^^^^^__-
   | |                                |
   | |                                expected 2 arguments
44 | |         println!("calculating slowly...");
45 | |         thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
46 | |         num + num2
47 | |     });
   | |_____- supplied 1 argument
   |
note: associated function defined here
  --> src/main.rs:21:8
   |
21 |     fn new(calculation: T, multiplication : T) -> Cacher<T> {
```

**UPD**
Finally I found an explanation of the syntax with brackets:

[About round brackets in 'let v = (self.calculation)(arg);'](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-the-exact-rule-for-round-brackets-required-around-closure-invocations/46745/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closure type is declared to take one `u32` argument and return a `u32` value:

```
Fn(u32) -> u32
```

But the closure that you are providing accepts *two* arguments.  This suggests that the closure type should be changed to specify that closures should accept two arguments:

```
Fn(u32, u32) -> u32
```

Additionally, `Cacher::new()` is declared to accept *two* such closures, but you only pass one.

However, you will run into another problem when you fix that: both arguments are declared to be the same type (`T`) but closures each have their own distinct type, so this signature requires that you pass the exact same closure type twice, which is likely not what you intended.

You would need to introduce a second generic type parameter:

```
struct Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(u32, u32) -> u32,
    U: Fn(u32, u32) -> u32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<u32>,
    multiplication : U,
}

impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U>
where
    T:  Fn(u32, u32) -> u32,
    U:  Fn(u32, u32) -> u32,
{   
    fn new(calculation: T, multiplication : U) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        // ...
```

As this gets more complex, it may be easier to maintain and reason about your code if you use boxed closures, which have a small runtime performance penalty due to indirection to a heap allocation and dynamic dispatch, but may be worth not having to hassle with so many types:

```
struct Cacher
{
    calculation: Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32) -> u32>,
    value: Option<u32>,
    multiplication : Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32) -> u32>,
}

impl Cacher
{   
    fn new(
        calculation: impl Fn(u32, u32) -> u32,
        multiplication : impl Fn(u32, u32) -> u32
    ) -> Cacher {
        Cacher {
            calculation: Box::new(calculation),
            value: None, 
            multiplication: Box::new(multiplication),
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just practicing, breaking down the code from this chapter: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html

By the way, there is an interesting function here:
`
fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
       
        match self.value {
            Some(v) =>  v,
            None => {
                let mut v  =  (self.multiplication)(arg);
                self.value = Some(v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
`

I still do not understand the meaning of `let mut v = (self.multiplication)(arg);,` if you can just

`let mut v = arg;`

Comment: @Timur `(self.multiplication)(arg)` invokes the closure stored in `self.multiplication`.

Comment: Thanks again! Nothing is clear, but better than yesterday))
I'll try to figure out where we put the closure in "calculation", which describes the syntax `(self.calculation)(arg)` or `(self.multiplication)(arg);` and why here `(arg)`.
It is a pity that debug or disassembler does not work here to understand what they do

Comment: `(arg)` is just the invocation of the function -- the arguments you are passing to it. Calling a function looks like `function(argument)`. Calling a closure looks like `closure_value(argument)`. In these cases the closure values are `self.calculation` and `self.multiplication`.

Comment: Still not sure what exactly `(self.calculation)` means here, it's a call to a closure - i.e. what exactly is happening. It's an instance of a structure. Or here `(self.multiplication)(arg)` we call the closure `casher::new(|num|`?
Good news - I found an explanation of the parenthesis syntax:
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-the-exact-rule-for-round-brackets-required-around-closure-invocations/46745

The question is in the link about the same article in rust-doc))

Comment: @Timur Yes, closures are effectively callable values. Function pointers are another type of callable value. `let x = |y| y + 1; assert_eq!(x(5), 6);`

Comment: Thank you again!
I have a deep misunderstanding of types and their declaration.
 structure element,
Calculation is type T, and we defined type T as Fn (function pointer), which takes u32 as input and produces -> u32.
This is what the entry means:
T: Fn(u32) -> u32.
Now when we call (self.calculation)(arg), we call the Cacher ::new function, because we have a pointer to this function (closure) with its parameters in the Cacher:: calculation structure.
Those. in fact, we can store a pointer to a closure function in the structure, with parameters, and call it. Finally got it!

Comment: @Timur _"when we call (self.calculation)(arg), we call the Cacher ::new function"_ -- No, you call whatever closure was _passed to_ `Cacher::new()`. Note also that `Fn(...) -> ...` is a trait implemented by closure types; `fn(...) -> ...` is a function pointer (note the difference in capitalization.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Also figured out the associated functions, thanks. In almost one line of code, here we create a new instance of Cacher(1) , filled with a closure(2), assigned to a variable(3).
I even played around with the online disassembler to figure it out. First this example with Cacher: [Cacher disasm](https://godbolt.org/z/P4j9453YK)
and my little example comparing function listing and closure  [my_disasm](https://godbolt.org/z/an97oajzd)